# Expressing (cos(x))^3 with sum/difference formulas

Tags: math

To express (cos(x))^2 we have (using the sum/diff formulas):

```
(cos(x))^2 => 1/2*(1+cos(2*x))
```

But how can we express (cos(x))^3?  Can this be done by using the same sum/diff formulas?  I know the answer is:

```
1/4*(3*cos(x) + cos(3*x)) => But how to get here?
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. Try [math.se] instead; but -- read their help center, something about formatting Latex, define the question properly (what exactly is "sum/diff formula"?).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the complex form,

```
cos(x) = (z + 1/z) / 2
```

where `z = exp(ix)`.

Then

```
cos³(x) = (z³ + 3z + 3/z + 1/z³) / 8 = (cos(3x) + 3 cos(x)) / 4
```

because

```
z³ = exp(i3x).
```

---

By the same method,

```
cos²(x) = (z² + 2 + 1/z²) / 4 = (cos(2x) + 1) / 2.
```

Comment: Thanks.  What happens to 1/z^2? does it get ignored because it's the imaginary part?

Comment: Got it.  Thanks.